# Do HTTPS Reverse Proxies without CONNECT exist?

Tags: https, connect, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to have an HTTPS Reverse Proxy without issuing CONNECT message?
Do those kind of proxies exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Not "reverse" proxy but forward proxy is the answer in this case.